# Deploying Rails with Capistrano, undefined method upcase for nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, capistrano

Deploying a Rails app to a new server, for the first time.

Running `cap production deploy --trace` gives me:

```
** Invoke production (first_time)
** Execute production
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
cap aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `upcase' for nil:NilClass
/Users/dfaulken-af/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.14.0/lib/sshkit/configuration.rb:90:in `logger'
/Users/dfaulken-af/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.14.0/lib/sshkit/configuration.rb:51:in `output_verbosity='
/Users/dfaulken-af/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.9.0/lib/capistrano/configuration.rb:94:in `block in configure_backend'
/Users/dfaulken-af/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.14.0/lib/sshkit.rb:11:in `configure'
/Users/dfaulken-af/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.9.0/lib/capistrano/configuration.rb:92:in `configure_backend'
/Users/dfaulken-af/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.9.0/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/dfaulken-af/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `block in execute'
/Users/dfaulken-af/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `each'
/Users/dfaulken-af/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `execute'
/Users/dfaulken-af/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/dfaulken-af/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/dfaulken-af/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/dfaulken-af/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke'
/Users/dfaulken-af/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
/Users/dfaulken-af/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/dfaulken-af/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
/Users/dfaulken-af/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
/Users/dfaulken-af/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/dfaulken-af/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
/Users/dfaulken-af/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
/Users/dfaulken-af/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/dfaulken-af/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/Users/dfaulken-af/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.9.0/lib/capistrano/application.rb:14:in `run'
/Users/dfaulken-af/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.9.0/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/dfaulken-af/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/cap:22:in `load'
/Users/dfaulken-af/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/cap:22:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => production
```

Which seems entirely confined to gem code. Before I open an issue with them (sshkit?), has anyone seen this before?

I use `Net::SSH::Config` to get the SSH user from my SSH config file. I know that those settings are correct, as I'm able to use them to log into the server.

```
remote_user = Net::SSH::Config.for('50.198.83.200')[:user] || ENV['USER']
server '50.198.83.200', user: remote_user, roles: %w(app db web)
```

But I've tried setting the remote user with `USER=the_user_name cap`, etc. and still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

My `log_level` line was incompletely written as

```
set :log_level
```

With no second argument.